# An exception occurred in processing searchresults.jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat

I am migrating a client's application from an old Tomcat VM hosted on Windows Server 2012 R2 to a new CentOS 7 VM after the former was hit by a ransomeware attack. My issue arises when I try to use the search function which queries a local `MySQL` database. My SQL knowledge is limited, so I'd appreciate all the help I can get from you wise and experienced coders out there. Here is the error I'm encountering:

[image: Error message]

From `searchresults.jsp`, the referenced lines are:

```
<!--    Find Diacritic Terms            -->
<c:set var="dsqlstatement">
        SELECT *
        FROM diacritic_map
        WHERE alternate LIKE '%<%= t %>%'
</c:set>

<sql:query var="rs_diacritics" dataSource="jdbc/balanchine">
        ${dsqlstatement}
</sql:query>
```

I have tested and verified that the database connection works, so it's probably an issue with the SQL statement itself right? Well I checked on the production server and the statement was indeed the same and functional, so now I'm running out of ideas. I am using MySQL version 8.0.15, Tomcat version 9.0.16, and `Java` version 1.8.0_191 if that information is useful.

Thank you in advance for any help you might offer.

Edit 1: Thank you for the recommendation @Selaron Here is the full stacktrace

[image: stacktrace]

Edit 2: Thank you as well @vancleff. Here is a sample application that I modified to test the database connection. I am still running into an error, but it's different now that I placed the mysql-connector-java-5.0.x-bin.jar file in the webapp's lib folder like you advised. This helped with the last error, but now I'm still getting something similar. It also revealed that I still had windows line endings in all of these files, so I ran dos2unix on the webapp's directory. Thanks for pointing this out!

[image: db connection test]

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample Application JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor=white>

<table border="0">
<tr>
<td align=center>
<img src="images/tomcat.gif">
</td>
<td>
<h1>Sample Application JSP Page</h1>
This is the output of a JSP page that is part of the Hello World application.
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<%= new String("Hello!") %>

<h1>Connection Status</h1>
<% 
try{
    String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DatabaseName-REDACTED";
    Connection connection = null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "User-REDACTED", "Password-REDACTED");
    if(!connection.isClosed())
            out.println("Successfully connected to " + "MySQL server using TCP/IP...");
            connection.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
            out.println("Unable to connect to database.\n"+e);
    }%>
</body>
</html>
```

New error:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765354/how-to-pass-param-from-a-query-to-another-jsp-page) out

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full stack trace. The stack trace from log file might be more complete than the one presented in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Download mysql-connector.jar from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.6) and add it to your classpath One more thing add

```
  <sql:setDataSource  var="datasrc"   driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
                            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname"

                            user="root"
                            password="pass"
                            />
    <sql:query var="rs_diacritics" dataSource="${datasrc}">
        ${dsqlstatement}
    </sql:query>
```

It seems you have not added mysql jar to the classpath and did not initialize the datasource correctly. Also, make sure to upload textual logs rather than photos/screenshots. They are not readable :)

Also, paste the jar inside lib and add to classpath:

```
WebContent
         |
         |__WEB-INF
                  |
                  |__lib
                       |
                       |__mysql-connector-java-5.0.x-bin.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Sorry it took forever for me to respond, but I did previously download the connector, add it to my classpath, and test it out by modifying a sample "Hello World" application. I'll edit the original post with the code and screencap. Thanks for your suggestion though! I think we're narrowing in on the crux of the problem.

Comment: Also, I didn't actually say this, but the data source is actually set in the same file as the sql statement in the manner you described. There's just a lot of code in between that and the statement that kicks the exception so I didn't want to post a lot of unnecessary information. Thanks again for taking the time to help :)

Comment: In your logs it says that mysql driver is not in class path see here to fix this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29263498/java-classpath-cannot-find-mysql-driver